# Can't install term3 on Atom. (ubuntu)

Tags: atom-editor, apm

I looked for similar issues but none really worked for me. Here's the error message;

Installing “term3@0.22.1” failed.Hide output…

> ptyw.js@0.4.1 install /tmp/apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy/node_modules/term3/node_modules/ptyw.js
>   node-gyp rebuild

```
npm WARN deprecated react-tools@0.11.2: react-tools is deprecated.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: This is most likely not a problem with node-gyp or the package itself and
gyp ERR! stack is related to network connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad 
gyp ERR! stack network settings.
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:197:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestError (/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:884:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:382:9)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy/node_modules/term3/node_modules/ptyw.js
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ptyw.js@0.4.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ptyw.js@0.4.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

npm ERR!     /home/mathieu/.atom/.apm/_logs/2019-10-23T13_29_53_626Z-debug.log

I tried to look for resolve the issue looking inside /.atom/.apm/_logs

```
1996 warn enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy/package.json'
1997 verbose enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
1998 warn apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No description
1999 warn apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No repository field.
2000 warn apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No README data
2001 warn apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy No license field.
2002 verbose stack Error: ptyw.js@0.4.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
2002 verbose stack Exit status 1
2002 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
2002 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
2002 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
2002 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
2002 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
2002 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
2003 verbose pkgid ptyw.js@0.4.1
2004 verbose cwd /tmp/apm-install-dir-119923-3780-17r1b00.uzsy
2005 verbose Linux 5.0.0-32-generic
2006 verbose argv "/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/snap/atom/238/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/mathieu/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/mathieu/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "https://www.atom.io/api/packages/term3/versions/0.22.1/tarball" "--target=3.1.10" "--disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
2007 verbose node v10.2.1
2008 verbose npm  v6.2.0
2009 error code ELIFECYCLE
2010 error errno 1
2011 error ptyw.js@0.4.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
2011 error Exit status 1
2012 error Failed at the ptyw.js@0.4.1 install script.
2012 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

2013 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

It seems to be a network issue. I looked for a proxy installed but found nothing. I'm relatively new to IT and I would really like to understand the problem so I can fix it.

I have also install other packages without any issue.

I appreciate any direction, suggestions and solutions. Thank you !

Comment: same problem here...

Comment: Still happening ...